# Flutter App used if condition inside list view

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

resived data is part and else part. I need return if part data only. I not need else part data data and nood continule loop. I tryed return null, after not working loop. I dont need view elase part value and don't neeed alocate physical space in mobile view. Please help.

Comment: you can try  `return Container();`

Comment: I tryed return Container(); it is not working.no show any value

Comment: what would you like to show??

Comment: Always resived adress for if and else parat . I need show ony if part values only.

Comment: we return text in if and elase part show all the adress. But i need show only if part adress

Comment: As far as I understood you want to return data based on if condition and ignore the else? And can you tell how many elements are their in your list view. Or add the photo of your expected result.

Comment: So many items available in list view we get data used api. https://findoctors.in/api/85f7536c8e07c5/chemists

Comment: It is hard to understand your code as there's no count till what you listview should be built even no usage of index in your item builder so it would be better if you share your code of fetching data from your api.

Comment: already data come correctly to if and else status. we need ignore else part and continue our list view

Answer (score 1):

In ListView.builder, you have to return something as it can be empty widget SizedBox()

You can use conditional statements in this

Like this code below :-

```
    ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return index > 5 ? Text('Hello') : SizedBox();
      },
    ),
```

Another option is for loop where you don't want to return else part :-

```
    int index = 5;

    Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) if (distance != null && distance <= 50) Text('Hello'),
      ],
    ),
```

```
    List<String> iterable = ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast'];
  
    for (String element in iterable) print(element);
```

**Don't use brackets for** *for loop* **it may reflect error.**

Comment: can't used sizebox(). sizebox() is genarate empty value but alocate free space every sizebox() return. that is problem. we can't used this solution.

Comment: Check out the new code snippet using `for loop`.

Comment: I tried to add for loop. but error with index error is "The type 'int' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable.dartfor_in_of_invalid_type
"

Comment: can you pls share your snippet, then only I can grab the syntax error.

Comment: List<String> iterable = ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast'];
  for (String element in iterable) print(element);

or
  
int iterable = 5;
  for (int i =0; i < iterable; i++) print(i);

Answer (score 0):

1. In ListView.builder, we couldn't able to skip the child. Because, every index it should allocate the space if you didn't return the child it will automatically allocate space for else part too.
2. Instead of that you should only manually skip the data you should don't want in your view.
3. If your fetching the data from cloud based, your should cast the snapshot to List or your using the local data
4. After extracting data from the snapshot, you should skip the element that you not required from it.

---

```
List<int> data = [100, 200, 50, 60, 10]; // your retrieved data example.

/// from that skip data that you didn't required from the condition
var dataList = data.where((value)=> value != null && value <=50).toList();
        

ListView.builder(
              itemCount: dataList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(dataList[index].toString()),
                );
              },
            );
```

Comment: we used this api to get data. https://findoctors.in/api/85f7536c8e07c5/chemists .

Comment: We don't have any limit list

Comment: findoctors.in/api/85f7536c8e07c5/chemists . --> I have tried to fetch data from this, but it returning null, could you share the fetching code snippet. It will help me to understand more clear an provide the required answer

Comment: findoctors.in/api/85f7536c8e07c5/chemists

Comment: please used above apk

Comment: body: 
      Column (
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if ( distance != null && distance <=  50) {
                      return (Text("Dara"))
                  }
                  else {

                  }
                
              }
                );
                
                
                )]))